# Loading FBconnect graph queries into Three20 TTTableViewDataSource

Tags: ios, datasource, three20

I've seen the usage of 'TTURLRequest' and 'requestDidFinishLoad' for creating DataSource, but how can I use FBconnect 'request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result'?

It won't work like TTURLRequest - won't wait for the dataSource to load and I can't call 'requestDidFinishLoad' at the end of the method because it hasn't a 'TTURLRequest' object with it's data...

Can I do that someway?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i managed to do this and it worked out well.
in my TTTableViewDataSource subclass method load:more: i did this to invoke modelDidStartLoad: before initiating the request

```
[delegates perform:@selector(modelDidStartLoad:) withObject:self];
[fbconnection requestWithGraphPath:.. andParams:.. andDelegate:self];
```

and the facebook delegate methods request:didLoad: & request:didFailWithError: similarly do, either after successfully reading the response or failing, one of

```
[delegates perform:@selector(modelDidFinishLoad:) withObject:self];

[delegates perform:@selector(didFailLoadWithError:) withObject:self withObject:error];
```

Comment: Thank you! but what is "delegates" who receives those operations?

Comment: _TTTableViewDataSource_ implements _delegates_ method to conform to the _TTModel_ protocol. Not exactly sure who the delegates are, but the goal is behave like _requestDidFinishLoad_ right? look at TTURLRequestModel.m and TTModel.m, _TTURLRequestModel_'s _requestDidFinishLoad_ calls through to _[self didFinishLoad]_ which is implemented in _TTModel_ and does _[delegate perform:...]_ as above. (a TTTableViewDataSource can't simply call _[self didFinishLoad]_, it conforms to the _TTModel_ protocol, but unlike _TTURLRequestModel_ it doesn't subclass from _TTModel_ class)